# Redirecionamento de URL mantendo o endereço

Tags: html, htaccess, redirecionamento

Estou usando meu servidor para hospedar outros sites pois meu plano de hospedagem permite, no entanto, gostaria de que, por exemplo, quando acessasse o diretório `www.meusite.com.br/outrosite` aparecesse na barra de endereços o domínio já redirecionado, como por exemplo `www.outrosite.com.br`.

Me disseram que tenho que colocar um código no `.htaccess` porém não sei qual código é esse.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fazer basicamente 2 coisas:

1) Registrar o dominio `outrosite.com.br` como "Addon domain" no painel de controle do seu servidor. Lá você configura o "document root", que poderá ser algo como `www.meusite.com.br/outrosite.com.br`.

2) Configurar o DNS na empresa onde registrou o domínio, apontando para o nameserver do seu servidor.